# Counterexample using counting measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, normed-spaces

While proving that the norm of the mulplicative operator from $L^2(X) \to L^2(X)$ is the
essential supremum of $|g|$ where $g \in L^\infty(X)$, I found that I need the $\sigma$-finiteness of the measure on $X$.

> Can someone give me an example of a non $\sigma$-finite measure space and $g \in L^\infty(X)$ such that the norm of the multiplication operator is strictly less than the essential supremum of $|g|$?

I was trying with the counting measure on $\mathbb R$, but to no avail, so it would be nice if someone can give me the example using the counting measure,but other counterexamples are also welcome.
If somebody has any problem with the definition of a multiplicative operator, please refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88689/multiplication-operator-norm).
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not an expert in measure theory, but I don't think you need $\sigma$-finiteness. For what step did you (think you) need it?

Comment: In the proof given in the above link,what if S(e) is of infinite measure? If the measure is sigma finite you can still take a subset of S(e) having finite measure and work with it.

Comment: by the operator, you mean
$$M_g : L^2(X) \to L^2(X), \qquad M_g[f] := fg$$
Where do you need $\sigma$-finiteness for the norm?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that and I have already explained your 2nd question.

Comment: And which space should be equipped with the countig measure instead of the Lebesgue measure? $L^2$ or $L^\infty$?

Comment: The measure on X should be equipped with the counting measure.

Comment: Ah, okay, what you need is that every (measurable) subset of infinite measure has a (measurable) subset of finite positive measure. That is the case for the counting measure, so you won't find counterexamples there. $\sigma$-finiteness guarantees that property, but is (far) more restrictive.

Comment: Ok,then give me any counterexample.

Comment: See Davide's answer (and upvote it).

Comment: @Fischer:Do such type of measure spaces have any special name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $X:=\{a,b\}$ and $\mu\{a\}=1$, $\mu\{b\}=\infty$. Define $g(a)=0$ and $g(b)=M\gt 0$. Since $L^2(X)=\{f\mid f(b)=0\}$, we have $M_g=0$ while $\lVert g\rVert_\infty=M$.