# Calculation of operator norm of some operator $L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given an operator $T: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ which is a composition $T = A(id - B)$ where $A$ takes $f(x) \in L^2[0,1]$ to $xf(x)$ and $B$ takes $f(x)$ to $\int^{1}_{0} f(t)dt$.

It is easy for me to see that $T$ is bounded because $\|T\| \leq \|A\| + \|B\| \leq 2$ but how do I calculate the norm of $T$?

Comment: Have you tried to get both of those inequalities to be equalities?

Comment: @mathworker21, I am pretty sure that the norm is not equal to 2, my guess the answer is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\|A\|=1$ (see [Show that the norm of the multiplication operator $M_f$ on $L^2[0,1]$ is $\|f\|_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88689/show-that-the-norm-of-the-multiplication-operator-m-f-on-l20-1-is-f)). Moreover
$$\|(I-B)f\|_2^2=\int_0^1\left(f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)dt\right)^2dx=\|f\|_2^2-\left(\int_0^1f(t)dt\right)^2\leq \|f\|_2^2$$
and the equality holds for $f(x)=2\sqrt{2}(x-1/2)$ with $\|f\|_2=1$. Hence $\|I-B\|=1$.

Now the operator norm is compatible with the composition and 
$$\|T\|\leq \|A\|\cdot\|I-B\|=1.$$ 
Finally, $\|T\|=1$ follows by considering the functions $f_n(x)=\sqrt{2n+1}\,x^n$. Then $\|f_n\|_2=1$, and, as $n$ goes to infinity,
$$\|Tf_n\|_2^2=\int_0^1x^2\left(f(x)-\int_0^1f(t)dt\right)^2 dx
=\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}-\frac{2(2n+1)}{(n+3)(n+1)}+\frac{2n+1}{3(n+1)^2}\to 1.
$$

P.S. We may also use $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n}\,1_{[1-1/n,1]}(x)$.